# Why some of my lazy-loaded module can't be found and others can?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, lazy-loading, angular-module

My app is using lazy-loading to load the necessary modules with the routes. All my modules are lazy-loaded with the same route, declared in my tsconfig.json. Most of them works fine, but for some reason, one is still throwing this error.

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'TemplateModule' in '@blockframes/material'`

The path @blockframes/material is declared in a tsconfig.ts file and refers to this

`"@blockframes/material": ["libs/material/src/index.ts"]`

Other libraries are imported the same way and lazy-loading works like a charm on them. The strangest things here is that I lazy-load 2 modules from the material library and only one seems to works without error.

Here's a look of my routes in app-routing-module:

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'layout', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: '@blockframes/auth#AuthModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'layout',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard, OrganizationListGuard],
    canDeactivate: [OrganizationListGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'organization',
        loadChildren: '@blockframes/organization#OrganizationModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'account',
        // loadChildren: '@blockframes/account#AccountModule' // TODO this fail with "Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'AccountModule' in '@blockframes/account'"
        loadChildren: 'libs/account/src/lib/account/account.module#AccountModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        canActivate: [MovieListGuard],
        canDeactivate: [MovieListGuard],
        loadChildren: '@blockframes/movie#MovieModule'
      },
      { path: 'templates',
        // loadChildren: '@blockframes/material#TemplateModule' // TODO this fail with "Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'TemplateModule' in '@blockframes/material'"
        loadChildren: 'libs/material/src/lib/template/template.module#TemplateModule'
      },
      {
        path: ':movieId',
        canActivate: [MovieActiveGuard],
        canDeactivate: [MovieActiveGuard],
        loadChildren: '@blockframes/material#DeliveryModule'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'not-found',
    loadChildren: '@blockframes/ui#ErrorNotFoundModule'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'not-found'
  }
];
```

As you can see, I got the same problem with @blockframes/account. You can also take note that @blockframes/material#DeliveryModule is sucessfully lazy-loaded, event if TemplateModule got the same architecture as DeliveryModule.

I realised that I can change my absolute paths to the @blockframes paths (for Template and Account) and the app will still run after rebuild. If I stop the server and `ng serve`, I'll get the Cannot find module error again.

I tried to rename my module, as material could be keyword, but it didn't  solve the problem.

Thanks a lot for your attention, if you got any questions about this problem I'll be happy to answer it as fast as I can.

Comment: I had a situation where I was having trouble with a project of mine (a @nrwl-based-project) not finding the lazy libraries too. In my case, I had to include all the lazy libraries in the `tsconfig.app.json` in the `include` attribute array (something like `"include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "../../../libs/my-lazy-load-library/src/index.ts"]`

Comment: It seems that I can't lazy-load two modules from same library at the same level. For example, if I comment my `@blockframes/material#DeliveryModule`, my TemplateModule doesn't got error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems we can't lazy-load two modules from sale library at the same level AT LEAST with the same path, this seems to works (until someone find a more elegant way to solve this)

In tsconfig.json

```
"@blockframes/material": ["libs/material/src/index.ts"],
"@blockframes/template": ["libs/material/src/index.ts"]
```

In app-routing-module

`@blockframes/template#TemplateModule`

As a bonus, a colleague told me that Angular 8 will import dynamic imports. We could import this way :

`import('@blockframes/material').then(x => x.TemplateModule)`